# Why is SQL Server cutting of first four letters of a column name?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server is returning unexpected results from a similarly named table.

This one has me puzzled. Selecting column names from `sys.columns` and the GUI indicate the column name is `attachmentid`. However the statement

```
select attachmentid from attachment
```

generates an error

> Invalid column name 'attachmentid'

The statement

```
select * from attachment
```

returns a column named `fileattachmentid` instead. So I did a little exploration and found that there's also a table called `fileattachment`. It seems that SQL Server is returning the results from the `fileattachment` table instead of `attachment`.

Wrapping the table name in double quotes does not solve the issue. They are both in the same schema. The only thing I can think of is the word "file" is restricted and SQL server is mis-selecting the table somehow. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of Attachment and Query]

[image: Unioning both tables returns a valid result]

[image: Querying sys.columns and sys.tables]

[image: GUI List of Databases in my SSMS]

Comment: Your columns query indicates that the two tables have a different number of columns. A `union` on differently shaped tables (ie different column count, names don't matter) won't work ... Clearly you are not executing all this queries on the same database ...

Comment: *If* what you say is really true then you will get an error if you run this, @afriendlydev . do you? `DECLARE @Schema sysname = N'dbo', @Table sysname = N'attachment', @SQL nvarchar(MAX), @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
DECLARE @delimiter nvarchar(20) = N',' + @CRLF + N'       ';

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT ' + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.[name]),@delimiter) + @CRLF + N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + N';'
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.object_ID = OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@Schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@Table));

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;`

Comment: @derpirscher. Yes exactly, unless SQL Server is routing the attachment table to fileattachment for some reason... Thats why I added the union query since it shouldnt be possible. Would a screenshot of eveything minimized in my gui prove it? You'll see there is only one connection and a single database within. I've been working in SQL Server for 8+ years, and I've never encountered something like this before which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @Larnu, unfortunately I cannot run that query, this is the read-only backend of a Dynamics 365 System and it does not allow me to use EXEC or any stored procedures of any kind. I get "unsupported" errors trying to run them. Not sure if that has something to do with the weird behavior

Comment: @afriendlydev Is it possible you have view with the same name but different column alias? With same names, views get referenced before tables I believe

Comment: @Rajat I thought that could be it too (Doesnt quite explain the odd behavior), but this database has zero views within

Comment: @afriendlydev Maybe the right table is in a different server than you're connected to? I would using fully qualified names (including server) to see if something different pops up

Comment: @larnu, running your query without executing it or storing it in the SQL variable generates a result of NULL. I am assuming some string result was expected so it could be passed to EXEC. Not sure if that helps

Comment: What about finding the object_id? Try this. `select object_id('attachment')`. Maybe the problem is your default schema is not dbo and your default has a synonym named attachment. Also try `select * from sys.objects where name in ('attachment', 'fileattachmet')`

Comment: @SeanLange select object_id('attachment') returns Null as does select object_id('fileattachment'). Select * from sys.schemas returns a single result of "dbo". The select * from sys.objects returns two rows as expected.

Comment: If `@SQL` has a value of `NULL` then no object called `dbo.attachment` exists in the database you ran it on.

Comment: @larnu, or object_id doesnt run properly in this instance. From the screenshots there is clearly an object called attachment, and another called fileattachment otherwise I wouldnt be getting results back. Do you know how to reach out to MSSQL support if such a thing exists? Seems like this may be an actual bug, either in SQL Server or Dynamics 365.

Comment: `column_id` of `10002` seems suspiciously high. There may well be relevant information if we could see the **whole** of `sys.columns` and `sys.objects` output not just the fragments you've deigned to share

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take this to our Microsoft Support plan, I have a feeling this may be happening from the database being the backend for a Microsoft Dynamics 365 application. That or SQL Server is stripping out the reserved keyword "file" from the fileattachments table, and since it has the lower objectid, its getting returned first when it goes hunting for the attachment table.

To sum up the suggested reasons for this issue:

1. I am in the wrong database (I am not as there is only one SQL Server database I have ever connected to and I can only see one database listed in the GUI)
2. I am swapping connections (I am not as this is the only connection I have ever made in SSMS on this machine)
3. I have multiple schemas (There is only one schema according to sys.schemas...dbo)
   4.Someone is modifying the tables,columns,etc. (that would be concerning since I am the only developer on staff and wouldnt explain how the column/table names remain the same after refreshing the GUI repeatedly)
4. It could be a view (there are no views in the database, attachment and fileattachment are also both tables)
5. I have no idea what I am doing (Maybe some days, but today I am feeling pretty confident I am not crazy)

A quick summary of queries I ran and the results that were outputted (I cant post a screenshot yet).

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(); -- Default schema, returns "dbo"
select * from sys.databases; -- Returns 1 row of my organizations database
SELECT * from sys.schemas; -- Returns 1 row, name of "dbo", schema_id of 1, and principal_id of 1
select * from sys.tables t where t.name in ('attachment', 'fileattachment') and t.schema_id = 1;
select * from sys.views
-- returns two rows for the tables fileattachment and attachment
select object_id('dbo."attachment"') ;--returns null
select object_id('"attachment"'); --returns null
select object_id('attachment'); --returns null
select object_id('fileattachment'); --returns null
select object_id('sys.tables');  -- returns -386, so object_id does in fact execute within this database
select distinct type_Desc FROM sys.objects  -- returns foreign_key_constraints, and user_table ... no views

SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(*)) 
FROM attachment;
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(*)) 
FROM fileattachment;
--return the exact same result;
```